# Batch renaming with part of file name in ascending order with the original name at back in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to batch rename files with part of name in ascending order with the orginal text at back in PowerShell.
Example:

original name

```
B121112.dwg
B122222.dwg
B123334.dwg
```

New name

```
01028-110697-001-A-2-20-001 B121112.dwg
01028-110697-002-A-2-20-001 B122222.dwg
01028-110697-003-A-2-20-001 B123334.dwg
```

I tried the following  which was posted on here but then I lose the original name

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.dwg | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('01028-110697-{0:D3}-A-2-20-001.dwg' -f $i++)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another placeholder in the template string for the new name and fill that with the file's `BaseName`.

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.dwg' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('01028-110697-{0:D3}-A-2-20-001 {1}.dwg' -f $i++, $_.BaseName)
}
```

---

Following up on your comment where the files do not always have the '.dwg' extension, you can change the above code to

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' -File | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('01028-110697-{0:D3}-A-2-20-001 {1}{2}' -f $i++, $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)
}
```

Mind you, this will rename **ALL files in the folder**.
If you want to rename only certain files, either use

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' -File -Include '*.dwg','*.tif','*.pdf' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('01028-110697-{0:D3}-A-2-20-001 {1}{2}' -f $i++, $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)
}
```

which will also rename files with the given extensions inside any subfolders you may have.

If you do not want recursion, and rename only files in the given root folder, you may do something like

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' -File | 
    Where-Object { '.dwg','.tif','.pdf' -contains $_.Extension } |
    ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('01028-110697-{0:D3}-A-2-20-001 {1}{2}' -f $i++, $_.BaseName, $_.Extension)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I didn’t know. Thanks!

Comment: I now have a folder with multiple types of files. How do I modify the above code to include all types of files? For example dwg , tif and pdf.

Comment: @RomaineVeggum Please see the edited answer. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I open Powershell by right clicking within the folder I want the names changed. My understanding is that then PowerShell only works within that folder. Is it still necessary to add the path?

Comment: @RomaineVeggum No, the `-Path` is there to rule out any mistakes if you happen not to be in that directory.

Comment: Sorry I managed it myself. I just removed -Path 'TheFolderWhereTheFilesAre' and it worked. Thank you for your help!